# I get a error in this sql statement in java, but it works in SQLite Studio. It says something is wrong near 'from'

Tags: java, android, sql

I made this query on SQLite studio and now I am using it on a Android Application in Android Studio. In SQLite Studio, I get exactly what I need, but it closes the app whenever I call it on Android. The error message is:

**Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.buraji.buraji/br.com.buraji.buraji.kanji_detalhes}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "from": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select Kunyomi.leitura, Kunyomi. from Kunyomi where Kunyomi.idKanji = 1**

```
select 
    Kunyomi.leitura,
    \'くん\'as tipo, 
    VocabularioKun.vocabulario,
    VocabularioKun.hiragana, 
    VocabularioKun.traducao, 
    VocabularioKun.exemploKanji,   
    VocabularioKun.exemploHiragana, 
    VocabularioKun.exemploTraducao 
from Kunyomi 
inner join VocabularioKun on Kunyomi._id = VocabularioKun.idKunyomi 
where Kunyomi.idKanji = 1 
union 
select 
    Onyomi.leitura,
    \'おん\' as tipo,
    VocabularioOn.vocabulario, 
    VocabularioOn.hiragana, 
    VocabularioOn.traducao, 
    VocabularioOn.exemploKanji, 
    VocabularioOn.exemploHiragana, 
    VocabularioOn.exemploTraducao 
from Onyomi join VocabularioOn on Onyomi._id = VocabularioOn.idOnyomi 
where Onyomi.idKanji = 1
```

The string I am using is as follows:

```
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("select Kunyomi.leitura, \'くん\'as tipo, VocabularioKun.vocabulario, VocabularioKun.hiragana, VocabularioKun.traducao, VocabularioKun.exemploKanji, VocabularioKun.exemploHiragana, VocabularioKun.exemploTraducao from Kunyomi join VocabularioKun on Kunyomi._id = VocabularioKun.idKunyomi where Kunyomi.idKanji = 1 union select Onyomi.leitura,\'おん\' as tipo, VocabularioOn.vocabulario, VocabularioOn.hiragana, VocabularioOn.traducao, VocabularioOn.exemploKanji, VocabularioOn.exemploHiragana, VocabularioOn.exemploTraducao from Onyomi inner join VocabularioOn on Onyomi._id = VocabularioOn.idOnyomi where Onyomi.idKanji = 1", null);
```

I have no idea why there's this second Kunyomi. in the error message. It's not on the query. Any help please?

Comment: Please, format the error message, and try to execute the query without these 2 lines `\'おん\' as tipo,` and `\'くん\'as tipo,` Probably, it is escape characters issue.

Comment: I tried that already, the error persists

Comment: In the line   \'くん\'as tipo, you need a space before `as`.  Just like you have in the second half of the union.

Comment: I was able to correct the first mistake, but now it says the column _id does not exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably means that the column `_id` doesn't exist.

Comment: It does, but I think when I called it separately, there was ambiguity because there were two _id columns, one for each table. When I use *, it works without a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by putting a wild card instead of the various selects statements and it worked. I have no idea why:

```
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("select *, 'くん' as tipo " +
            "from Kunyomi, " +
            "VocabularioKun " +
            "where Kunyomi._id = VocabularioKun.idKunyomi " +
            "and Kunyomi.idKanji = 18" +
            " union " +
            "select *, 'おん' as tipo " +
            "from Onyomi, " +
            "VocabularioOn  where  Onyomi._id = " +
            "VocabularioOn.idOnyomi and Onyomi.idKanji = 18", null);
```